# Creating multi column and multi page pdfs with FPDF

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf

I am trying to utilize the FPDF module with Laravel (crabbly/fpdf-laravel)

The need is to create a 1+ page 3-column documents.
In the essence, I have a list of pairs TERM:DESCRIPTION that I need to output one after another. I am struggling with the overall logic and I am not even sure if I am doing it the right way and wondering if there is a better solution to this (whoever is familiar with FPDF)

1. Get the list of Term:Description pairs ($glossary)
2. Separate each Description into lines that are below 75 characters in length
3. Count how many lines already in the column
4. Add lines to the coumn
5. Switch Page/Column when numbers of lines exceed the defined length of 51 lines per column

This is the code I came up with:

```
public function getCreatePDF($flascard_id) {
    $flashcard = Flashcard::where('user_id', auth()->id())->findOrFail($flascard_id);

    $glossary = Glossary::with('flashcarditem')
            ->whereHas('flashcarditem', function ($query) use ($flascard_id) {
                $query->where('flashcard_id', '=', $flascard_id);
            })
            ->get();

    $pdf = app('FPDF');
    $pdf->col = 0;
    $pdf->AcceptPageBreak(false);
    //My Loop Controls
    $column = 0; //Control which column to add data
    $columnLenght = 0; //monitor if we need to change the column
    $maxLinesPerColumn = 51;
    $wrapCharacters = 75; //do not exceed this char qty per line
    $collectedDescription = ""; //stack Description here

    $pdf->AddPage(['L', 'Letter']);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B');
    $pdf->SetFontSize(18);
    $mid_x = 135; // the middle of the "PDF screen", fixed by now.        
    $pdf->Text($mid_x - ($pdf->GetStringWidth('TITLE') / 2), 102, 'TITLE');
    $pdf->AddPage(['L', 'Letter']);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(7);

    foreach ($glossary as $key => $g) {
        $chunks = explode("\n", wordwrap(strip_tags($g->description), $wrapCharacters));
        $actionCollect = 1;
        $collectedDescription = "";


        for ($i = 0; $i < count($chunks); $i++) {
            if ($columnLenght > $maxLinesPerColumn && $column == 2) {
                $column = 0;
                $columnLenght = 1;

                $pdf->AddPage(['L', 'Letter']);
                $pdf->Footer("d");
                $pdf->col = $column;
                $x = 10 + $column * 95;
                $pdf->SetLeftMargin($x);
                $pdf->SetX($x);
                $pdf->SetY(8);
                $actionCollect = 0;
            } else if ($columnLenght > $maxLinesPerColumn && $column < 2) {
                $columnLenght = 1;
                $column++;
                $pdf->col = $column;
                $x = 10 + $column * 95;
                $pdf->SetLeftMargin($x);
                $pdf->SetX($x);
                $pdf->SetY(8);
                $actionCollect = 0;
            } else {
                $columnLenght ++;
                $actionCollect = 1;
            }

            if ($i == 0) {
                $columnLenght ++;
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B');
                $term = html_entity_decode($g->term);
                $pdf->MultiCell(90, 3, $term, 'R');
                $pdf->Ln(0);
            }

            $collectedDescription.=strip_tags($chunks[$i]);

            if (count($chunks) - 1 && $i == 0) {

                $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
                $pdf->MultiCell(90, 3, $collectedDescription, 'R');
                $actionCollect = 0;
                $collectedDescription = "";
            } else {
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
                $pdf->MultiCell(90, 3, strip_tags($chunks[$i]), 'R');
                $actionCollect = 0;
                $collectedDescription = "";
            }
        }

        $pdf->Ln(1);
    }
}
```

My Desired state

[image: desired state]

Comment: And what does your code produce please?

Comment: My code kind of works (the screenshot); but it might not always overflow correctly if there are too many terms with short description (it breaks the page) or too few terms with long description(columns are not filled completely). I was hoping there is a built-in FPDF functionality that can help me to streamline my efforts